# Unable to display total using append

Tags: javascript

I am making a food delivery app. I would like that there would be a place whereby it would display the total. Right now, I am unable to display the total amount from multiplying quantity and price. It does not show up on the app.

And, there are no errors on the console too.

Javascript Code:

```
function _showorderResult(arr) {
    var value1 = arr[0].price;
    var value2 = arr[0].quantity;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        result = value1 * value2;

        htmlstring = "";

        $("#itemimage").html("<img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" +
            arr[i].imagefile + "' width='200'>");
        $("#price").html("Price" + ": " + " $" + arr[i].price);
        $("#itemname").html("Item" + ":" + arr[i].itemName);
        $("#quantity").html("Quanitiy" + ":" + arr[i].quantity);
        $("result").append(htmlstring);
        $("#requestedDateTime").html("To delivery by" + ":" + arr[i].requestedDateTime);
        $("#deliveredDateTime").html("Delivered on" + ":" + arr[i].deliveredDateTime)

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `htmlstring` to contain? You set it to an empty string and then do nothing else to it.

Comment: `$("result")` pretty sure that is the wrong selector you want to use, would also suggest checking that your other ones are correct

Answer (score 1):

> And, there are no errors on the console too.

There were plenty of errors in my console, but there are several mistakes here.  The first is that your code is not runnable.  Please consider making a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Next, you are misusing or not properly formatting the `append(...)` function.  That's intended to append HTML elements, not string values.

As the comments suggest, you seem to have confused `var result` and `$("result")`.  If you're not using the DOM selector, you probably don't want to jQuery-wrap your variables.  The proper jQuery-wrap syntax would have been `$(result)` without the double quotes, but please don't do that either, it doesn't offer any benefit over just `var result`.  `htmlstring` doesn't contain any actual HTML, so I've renamed it `runningTotal` instead and add it to the `price * quantity`.  This must be initialized first or you'll get `NaN`.

Make sure to initialize your variables.  To this point, there's some hard-coded indexes such as `value1 = arr[0].price` which make no sense in this pasted code.  We can assume you left these here after troubleshooting.  Please clean them up next time.

Finally, this is minor, but be consistent with your object names... e.g. `imagefile` versus `imageFile`.  It doesn't matter which you choose so as long as you're consistent.  This will help find typos down the road.

Here's a working example:

```
<html>
<img src="" id="itemimage">
<p id="price">Price: $0.00</p>
<p id="itemname">Item: None</p>
<p id="quantity">Quantity: None</p>
<p id="result">Running: None</p>
<p id="requestedDateTime">To delivery by: None</p>
<p id="deliveredDateTime">Delivered on: None</p>

<script>
var order = [{
  price: 5,
  quantity: 3,
  itemName: 'Pizza',
  imagefile: 'pizza.png',
  requestedDateTime: '12:00',
  deliveredDateTime: '12:30'
}];

/** Dummy function to allow code to run **/
var serverURL = function() { return ""; }

function _showorderResult(arr) {
    // var value1 = arr[0].price;
    // var value2 = arr[0].quantity;
    var result;
    var runningTotal = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        result = arr[i].price * arr[i].quantity;

        runningTotal += result;

        $("#itemimage").html("<img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].imagefile + "' width='200'>");
        $("#price").html("Price" + ": " + " $" + arr[i].price);
        $("#itemname").html("Item" + ":" + arr[i].itemName);
        $("#quantity").html("Quanitiy" + ":" + arr[i].quantity);
        $("#result").html("Running" + ":" + runningTotal);
        $("#requestedDateTime").html("To delivery by" + ":" + arr[i].requestedDateTime);
        $("#deliveredDateTime").html("Delivered on" + ":" + arr[i].deliveredDateTime);

    }
}

_showorderResult(order);
</script>
</html>
```